# Proof of the convexity of a support function!

Tags: convex-analysis

How can I prove the convexity and show $x$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $y$??

Let $S$ be a nonempty, bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be
defined as:   $ f(y)=sup_{x \in S}{ \ y^t*x}.$

Prove that $f$ is convex and show that if $f(y) = y^t*x$, where $x \in S$, $x$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $y$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see: 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If $f_\alpha$ is convex for all $\alpha$ then $f=\sup_\alpha f_\alpha$ is convex. This can be proved directly or by noting that the epigraph
of $f$ is the intersection of the epigraphs of $f_\alpha$.

Since each $y \mapsto y^T x$ is convex (in fact linear) it follows
that $y \mapsto \sup_{x\in S} y^T x$ is convex. (This has nothing to do
with the convexity of $S$.)

Suppose $f(y) = y^T x$ with $x \in S$. Note that
$f(y+h) \ge (y+h)^T x$ for all $h$.

Then
we have
$f(y+h) -f(y) \ge (y+h)^T x-y^T x = h^T x$ for all $h$, hence
$x \in \partial f(y)$.

Comment: Why  each $y \mapsto y^T x$ is convex?

Comment: @Anneliset.: Any linear (or affine) function is convex. It is also straightforward to check from the definition of convexity or note that the second derivative is $0$ which is positive semi definite.

Comment: I see and why $f(y+h) \ge (y+h)^T x,$ for all $h$? why did you change $=$ by $\ge?$

Comment: @Anneliset.: There is a nice duality with the nearest point to a compact convex set and the support function: $\min_{\|y\| \le 1} \max_{x \in S} y^T x =\max_{x \in S} \min_{\|y\| \le 1}  y^T x = - \min_{x \in S} \|x\|$.

Comment: I don't get it, we need to show that $x$ is a subgradient , so we need to find the $\ge$, I think you shouldn't write $f(y+h) \ge (y+h)^T x$ but $f(y+h) = (y+h)^T x$. And for your information I already took a break for the new year 

Comment: @Anneliset.: Sorry, I deleted a comment that was incorrect. What is meant by the question is that **if** $f(y) = y^T x$ for $x \in S$ (that is, $x$ is a maximiser) then $x$ is a subgradient. So we have $f(y+h) \ge (y+h)^T x$ (by definition of the support function and $f(y) = y^T x$ by assumption. Subtracting gives the required relationship that $f$ and a subgradient must satisfy.

Comment: @Anneliset. The function $f$ is **not** linear.

Comment: But why are you using the definition of support function? For the second question, i.e. to prove $x$ is a subgradient of $f$, $f$ is defined only as $f(y)=y^tx?$

Comment: @Anneliset.: No, the question is to show that for some $y$ if there is some $x$ such that $f(y) = y^Tx$ then $x \in \partial f(y)$. The question is poorly worded (it confused me earlier which is why I added an incorrect comment).

Comment: okay, I think I understand now, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, then why is there a hypothesis $S$ is convex? It does not look like it is necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @10understanding You would have to ask the OP that, I have no idea why.

Comment: @copper.hat The problem is also in the Bazaraa book, stated the same way. I was actually not just asking you, but the author/problem itself and all of us involved haha xD